# How to stop Windows 10 build 9926 from installing

Tags: windows, windows-10-preview

I'm on a brand new Dell XPS 15 and the new Technical Preview build 9926 is completely unusable. It's not compatible with my intel and Nvdia drivers and most of the time I get stuck on a black screen at boot. The only thing I can so is rollback to 9879 which works fine but that gives me about a half day before 9926 forces itself to install again. I have it set to slow now but it doesnt help. How can I stop it from installing after rollback?

Comment: You will have to wait until a new build is released.  I would just disable `Windows Updates` for the time being until you hear about a new build being released.